# Separating thousands

Tags: python, optimization

I have been coding for around half a year in uni and have done some side projects. This is one of them and although my code works for integers, I would like to know how it could be optimised using less lines of code. Coding at uni has taught me how to create many programs but not really how to optimise code and so any further tips would be greatly appreciated! <3

```
num = int(1230124013502)

def rem(num):
    """
    Rem function separates the thousands in an intiger and converts to 
    a string. Function takes one input (num) which must be of intiger 
    form. Rem converts to string with commas separating the thousands
    """
    num = str(num)
    l = len(num)
    remain = l%3
    sum = ''

    if remain == 0:
        remain = 3
    
    new = num[remain:]
    pre = num[:remain]
    
    #print(pre,new,remain)
    
    l_new = len(new)
    zeros = []
    
    for i in range(3,l_new+3,3):
        j = i - 3
        post = new[j:i] + ','
        zeros.append(post)
        
    for i in range(len(zeros)):
        sum += zeros[i]
    
    tot = pre + ',' + sum
    endpoint = len(tot) - 1
    tot = tot[0:endpoint]
    
    if l < 4:
        print(num)
        return num
    
    else: 
        print(tot)
        return tot
rem(num)
```

Comment: This is not even working: `NameError: name 'pre' is not defined`.

Comment: You can use `%1000`recursively  in the original number or... just convert it to string and add a comma every 3 digits from the right.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Stack Overflow is for *specific questions*, not necessarily "broken code". But you are right that this question is not specific and is off-topic for Stack Overflow, and would be on-topic for Code Review *assuming that the code actually works (which currently out-of-the-box, it does not)*.

Comment: Optimization: `print(f'{num:,}')`

Comment: The best optimization would be not re-inventing the wheel. Python comes battery included, Mark's solution seems to do what you need.